# Inner join on one PostgreSQL database table and another one is normal array

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL.
Can you please tell me why the below query is not working.

```
 Select * 
 from custom_test as dbtable 
   inner join aLocalArray as localtable on dbtable.id = localtable.id
```

Here custom_test is database table in PostgreSQL. aLocalArray is an array which is prepared by me.

Comment: not sure wha a "local array" but, are you maybe looking for `where dbtable.id = any(aLocalArray)`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this one because I am new to PostgreSQL..

Comment: @VASUNDHARALELLA Please show the value of `aLocalArray` and the definition of the `dbtable` table, otherwise we can hardly help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the array, you probably want to use [`UNNEST(array)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM custom_test AS dbtable
JOIN UNNEST (aLocalArray) AS localtable (id)
ON dbtable.id = localtable.id
```

But as suggested in the comments, the [`dbtable.id = any(aLocalArray)` predicate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) or even the `ARRAY[dbtable.id] @> aLocalArray` operator might also do the trick.